# Unable to change the title of header links

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, title

I am using a wordpress theme. I have configured it successfully, but when I try to place social icons, for instance, facebook on top, I need to change the title of the same from "Theme on facebook" to "click here to like". I tried to change the theme-options.php file under admin folder as well as header files, but to no success. Even I founded and replaced every title with "facebook", but it is still being showed as "Theme on facebook".

The below code under the file header-extensions.php is printing this code.

```
/****************************************************************************************/



if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_socialnetworks' ) ) :

/**

 * This function for social links display on header

 *

 * Get links through Theme Options

 */

function theme_socialnetworks( $flag ) {



    global $themee_theme_options_settings;

   $options = $theme_theme_options_settings;



    $theme_socialnetworks = '';

    if ( ( !$theme_socialnetworks = get_transient( 'theme_socialnetworks' ) ) && ( 1 == $flag ) )  {



        $theme_socialnetworks .='

            <div class="social-profiles clearfix">

                <ul>';



                $social_links = array(); 

                $social_links_name = array();

                $social_links_name = array( __( 'Facebook', 'theme' ),

                                            __( 'Twitter', 'theme' ),

                                            __( 'Google Plus', 'theme' ),

                                            __( 'Pinterest', 'theme' ),

                                            __( 'Youtube', 'theme' ),

                                            __( 'Vimeo', 'theme' ),

                                            __( 'LinkedIn', 'theme' ),

                                            __( 'Flickr', 'theme' ),

                                            __( 'Tumblr', 'theme' ),

                                            __( 'Myspace', 'theme' ),

                                            __( 'RSS', 'theme' )

                                            );

                $social_links = array(  'Facebook'      => 'social_facebook',

                                                'Twitter'       => 'social_twitter',

                                                'Google-Plus'   => 'social_googleplus',

                                                'Pinterest'     => 'social_pinterest',

                                                'You-tube'      => 'social_youtube',

                                                'Vimeo'         => 'social_vimeo',

                                                'Linked'            => 'social_linkedin',

                                                'Flickr'            => 'social_flickr',

                                                'Tumblr'            => 'social_tumblr',

                                                'My-Space'      => 'social_myspace',

                                                'RSS'               => 'social_rss'  

                                            );



                $i=0;

                foreach( $social_links as $key => $value ) {

                    if ( !empty( $options[ $value ] ) ) {

                        $theme_socialnetworks .=

                            '<li class="'.strtolower($key).'"><a href="'.esc_url( $options[ $value ] ).'" title="'.sprintf( esc_attr__( '%1$s on %2$s', 'theme' ), get_bloginfo( 'name' ), $social_links_name[$i] ).'" target="_blank">'.get_bloginfo( 'name' ).' '.$social_links_name[$i].'</a></li>';

                    }

                    $i++;

                }       



                $theme_socialnetworks .='

            </ul>

            </div><!-- .social-profiles -->';



        set_transient( 'theme_socialnetworks', $theme_socialnetworks, 86940 );   

    }

    echo $theme_socialnetworks;

}

endif;



/****************************************************************************************/
```

I even removed the full div, but it is still printing it.

Comment: What code have you tried? Post something from your header or the part which takes care of the social media links.

Comment: Just clear your cache and try again.

Comment: I was very sure this question was going to come, but mate, this is not an HTML/javascript/CSS issue that I am facing that I can post a code. I even cannot make a fiddle. Do you get my point?? The best way to debug it would be to check the link that I have posted and downloading it on your localhost and accessing it by a WYSIWYG editor to find all the links where it says "Facebook". Am I sounding good @berentrom ??

Comment: When I inspect your them that show on anger tag of your FB link. I think it can change on your header.php file on them folder.

Comment: sorry @Kannan couldn't get you .. Can you please elaborate so that I shall do it live ??

Comment: _“but do you expect me to post that hell lot of code here”_ – no, I expect you to do what I already said – identify _relevant_ parts of code, and post them here.

Comment: ok Sir @CBroe, let me try doing that one for you :)

Comment: Sir @CBroe, I have updated my question as per your guidance. You can have a look. (I appreciate your criticism when you did not got what you came to look for, but at the same time, I shall appreciate your contribution when I founded the MOST RELEVANT area which is where the issue is coming from.) Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to line 353 in library/structure/header-extensions.php to find the code for the output of these icons.

The layout is {BLOG NAME} on {SOCIAL NETWORK NAME}. It uses get_bloginfo( 'name' ) to get the name of your site. Is or has the title of your site been "Attitude"?

The icons use a transient and it's not clear from this file how that transient is cleared so if you've changed your site name and it's still showing up that will be why.

Run the following at the top of your functions.php to be sure.

```
delete_transient( 'attitude_socialnetworks' );
```

Remove after you've run once.

UPDATE: I just noticed you wanted to use "Facebook" etc as the titles. In that case you would modify line 353 of that file to:

```
'<li class="'.strtolower($key).'"><a href="'.esc_url( $options[ $value ] ).'" title="'.sprintf( esc_attr__( '%1$s', 'attitude' ), $social_links_name[$i] ).'" target="_blank">'.get_bloginfo( 'name' ).' '.$social_links_name[$i].'</a></li>';
```

Make sure to run the delete transient code after making this change.

Comment: Let me just try that .. +1 for your time and efforts .. Hope this works :)

Comment: No @Nathan it still shows the same, infact, I also removed the `%1$s on %2$s`, but it still prints this sting and shows the same :(

Comment: Did you delete the transient? If it's still showing like this you'll need to trace back the code from the header output.

Comment: I just deleted the full `<ul>` code, but it is still printing :O How can this happen?? - @Nathan

Comment: Was the UL code inside the transient?

Comment: Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/qAA5b/ (under the HTML section) - @Nathan

Comment: Did you delete the transient like I told you to? Anything that appears inside that transient will remain the same for the next day. You can remove it entirely but until the transient expires or you delete it everything will stay the same.

Comment: I have kept it as you mentioned on functions.php file, but I removed it when you had mentioned in your answer. There is no transient file now - @Nathan

Comment: I'm struggling to explain this but I can assure you the issue stems from the transient.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47939/discussion-between-nathan-lee-and-nathan-dawson)